# .htaccess rewrite url breaks css/javascript/other files

Tags: .htaccess

my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php/?node=$1 [L]
```

now when I include my css file with:

```
<link href="sitewide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it doesn't work. The same goes for javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider rewriting only non-existing paths, e.g. if file or directory exists - don't rewrite it.

Wordpress uses this to rewrite their permalinks, I think it's pretty good example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

As you can see they have rewrite conditions to exclude existing files/directories.

Answer (score 7):

I've been looking everywhere for an easy solution that wouldn't make me hardcode baselinks for all my relative paths, like imgs, css, javascript...

So here it goes, add this between the `<head>` tags of the pages you are having problems:

`<base href='http://www.mydomain.com/'>`

This will make that your relative path links will start with this base link. Simple as that.

The `<base>` tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document. Put the `<base>` tag as the first element inside the `<head>` element, so that other elements in the head section uses the information from the `<base>` element.

Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

That `.htaccess` file is redirecting anything that doesn't include a `/` to `index.php`.
Consider rewriting it to catch only the paths you *really* need.

Alternatively, you could start your file with a rule indicated as "Last" (`L`):

```
RewriteRule ^/javascript.js$ $0 [L]
```

This would force Apache to evaluate this RewriteRule and then halt all other rules for that request. Thus, your `.js` or `.css` files would be served properly, but you'd have to make a new entry in the `.htaccess` for every such file. I'd **strongly** recommend my first suggestion over this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php/?node=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it's what i need, and I have tried this but it returns with a 404 not found, however I have used RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php/?node=$1 [L]

and it seems to work.